# How to display multiple custom apps in Flutter (Android only)

Tags: flutter, dart

I use a library called `device_apps`  and I want to display few custom apps for which I know the `packageName`, but unfortunately when I try to display them nothing happen.
Below is my code and when you will tap on Custom Apps button you will understand what I’m talking about, of course if you have 2 minutes to test my code.
If anyone can help me to understand what I’ve done wrong I will really appreciate.

Here is the repository:

https://github.com/florentin89/displayCustomAppsFlutter/tree/main/lib

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:device_apps/device_apps.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomApps extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomApps({super.key});

  @override
  State<CustomApps> createState() => _CustomAppsState();
}

class _CustomAppsState extends State<CustomApps> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Custom Apps"),
      ),
      body: const _CustomAppsList(),
    );
  }
}

class _CustomAppsList extends StatefulWidget {
  const _CustomAppsList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<_CustomAppsList> createState() => _CustomAppsListState();
}

class _CustomAppsListState extends State<_CustomAppsList> {
  late Future<List<Application>>? myApps = [] as Future<List<Application>>?;

  Future<List<Application>>? loadMyApps() async {
    await DeviceApps.getApp('com.samsung.android.oneconnect')
        .then((oneConnect) => oneConnect != null
            ? myApps?.then((apps) => apps.add(oneConnect))
            : null)
        .whenComplete(() async =>
            await DeviceApps.getApp('com.sec.android.easyMover').then(
                (easyMover) => easyMover != null
                    ? myApps?.then((apps) => apps.add(easyMover))
                    : null))
        .whenComplete(() async =>
            await DeviceApps.getApp('com.samsung.android.timezone.autoupdate_O')
                .then((timeZoneUpdate) => timeZoneUpdate != null
                    ? myApps?.then((apps) => apps.add(timeZoneUpdate))
                    : null));

    return myApps!;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Application>>(
        future: loadMyApps(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Application>> data) {
          if (data.data == null) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            List<Application> apps = data.data!;

            return Scrollbar(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                    Application app = apps[position];
                    return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                          leading: app is ApplicationWithIcon
                              ? CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: MemoryImage(app.icon),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                )
                              : null,
                          onTap: () => onAppClicked(context, app),
                          title: Text('${app.appName} (${app.packageName})'),
                          subtitle: Text('Version: ${app.versionName}\n'
                              'System app: ${app.systemApp}\n'
                              'APK file path: ${app.apkFilePath}\n'
                              'Data dir: ${app.dataDir}\n'
                              'Installed: ${DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(app.installTimeMillis).toString()}\n'
                              'Updated: ${DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(app.updateTimeMillis).toString()}'),
                        ),
                        const Divider(
                          height: 1.0,
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: apps.length),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}

void onAppClicked(BuildContext context, Application app) {
  showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(app.appName),
          actions: <Widget>[
            _AppButtonAction(
              label: 'Open app',
              onPressed: () => app.openApp(),
            ),
            _AppButtonAction(
              label: 'Open app settings',
              onPressed: () => app.openSettingsScreen(),
            ),
            _AppButtonAction(
              label: 'Uninstall app',
              onPressed: () async => app.uninstallApp(),
            ),
          ],
        );
      });
}

class _AppButtonAction extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final VoidCallback? onPressed;

  const _AppButtonAction({required this.label, this.onPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        onPressed?.call();
        Navigator.of(context).maybePop();
      },
      child: Text(label),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my issue. I don't know if is the best, but at least is working fine.

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:device_apps/device_apps.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomApps extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomApps({super.key});

  @override
  State<CustomApps> createState() => _CustomAppsState();
}

class _CustomAppsState extends State<CustomApps> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Custom Apps"),
      ),
      body: const _CustomAppsList(),
    );
  }
}

class _CustomAppsList extends StatefulWidget {
  const _CustomAppsList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<_CustomAppsList> createState() => _CustomAppsListState();
}

class _CustomAppsListState extends State<_CustomAppsList> {
  /// Properties
  List<Application>? myApps = [];
  bool isLoading = false;

  /// Methods

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadRTApps();
  }

  Future<List<Application>>? loadRTApps() async {
    setState(() => isLoading = true);
    await DeviceApps.getApp('com.samsung.android.oneconnect')
        .then(
            (oneConnect) => oneConnect != null ? myApps?.add(oneConnect) : null)
        .whenComplete(() async =>
            await DeviceApps.getApp('com.sec.android.easyMover').then(
                (easyMover) =>
                    easyMover != null ? myApps?.add(easyMover) : null))
        .whenComplete(() async =>
            await DeviceApps.getApp('com.samsung.android.timezone.autoupdate_O')
                .then((timeZoneUpdate) => timeZoneUpdate != null
                    ? myApps?.add(timeZoneUpdate)
                    : null))
        .whenComplete(() => setState(() => isLoading = false));

    return myApps ?? [];
  }

  void onAppClicked(BuildContext context, Application app) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text(app.appName),
            actions: <Widget>[
              _AppButtonAction(
                label: 'Open app',
                onPressed: () => app.openApp(),
              ),
              _AppButtonAction(
                label: 'Open app settings',
                onPressed: () => app.openSettingsScreen(),
              ),
              _AppButtonAction(
                label: 'Uninstall app',
                onPressed: () async => app.uninstallApp(),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  /// Widgets
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isLoading
        ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
        : ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
              Application app = (myApps ?? [])[position];
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    leading: app is ApplicationWithIcon
                        ? CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: MemoryImage(app.icon),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          )
                        : null,
                    onTap: () => onAppClicked(context, app),
                    title: Text('${app.appName} (${app.packageName})'),
                    subtitle: Text('Version: ${app.versionName}\n'
                        'System app: ${app.systemApp}\n'
                        'APK file path: ${app.apkFilePath}\n'
                        'Data dir: ${app.dataDir}\n'
                        'Installed: ${DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(app.installTimeMillis).toString()}\n'
                        'Updated: ${DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(app.updateTimeMillis).toString()}'),
                  ),
                  const Divider(
                    height: 1.0,
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
            itemCount: myApps?.length);
  }
}

class _AppButtonAction extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final VoidCallback? onPressed;

  const _AppButtonAction({required this.label, this.onPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        onPressed?.call();
        Navigator.of(context).maybePop();
      },
      child: Text(label),
    );
  }
}
```